# Persistent syntax coloring in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, syntax

I am using TeXworks. I know the syntax coloring can be enable by choosing Format/Syntax Coloring/LaTeX. However I have to do this every time I open a `tex` file which is a bit annoying. Is there a possibility to make TeXworks render with syntax coloring all the time?

Is there maybe something similar to the `% !TEX root = main.tex` but for setting the syntax coloring?

Comment: Have you set it in the general preferences? For the first file you open, you do have to do it 'by hand' but after that the setting you flow from the general one.

Comment: I'm not on my PC with TeXworks just now, but in general, the options in _Format_ menu apply to the current window. A similar set of options is under _Preferences_, which applies to new windows. Also, there's no %! TeX` directive for this, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it in

> Edit->preferences->Editor->Syntax