# MiKTeX 22.3 TeXworks syntax coloring

Tags: miktex, texworks, syntax-highlighting

How do I set the colors for TeXworks (in MiKTeX 22.3) to use for syntax coloring?

My earlier installation of MiKTeX 2.9 had a file `C:\Users\R\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.6\configuration\syntax_patterns.txt`. However, my current installation of MiKTeX 22.3 appears not to have any directories named anything like `TeXworks`, or any file called `syntax_patterns`. I've had a look at some of the files in
`C:\Users\R\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\config`
but they appear not to be what I'm looking for.

[Edit->Preferences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294005) offers a choice of syntax regime, but does not enable the user to choose the colors.

Just to make it clear, I am not concerned here with the look of TeXworks's widgets. This [answer from 2017](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383313) concerns them but doesn't help me here.

An [answer from 2018](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461684) and the links in it don't help for this version: in an installation of MiKTeX 22.3, where is this file I must edit?

I installed MiKTeX 22.3 on a Windows 8.1 PC. As the installation wizard recommended, I chose the option "Install only for me".

Comment: Texworks settings are no longuer under `MiKtex`, but  in a `TUG` subfolder  of one of the 3 folders in your `AppData` directory. Anyway, in Texworks help menu, you have an option which provides a direct link to this folder (look for r'esources')

Comment: Found it! It was in `C:\Users\R\AppData\Roaming\TUG\TeXworks\configuration` --- though quite why Roaming and not Local, who knows. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: `Local` means linked to a specific computer, while `Roaming`means linked to your account in a context where you w'd able to use the same accout on different computer in a domain. For single user configuation, the distinction is void of signification.